Difference between docker buildx build and docker build for multi arch images
I have problem with understanding the difference between docker build vs docker buildx build commands in context of building multi arch images.
In docker documentation I see that docker build is alias for docker buildx build:
https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/buildx/build/
So I assume there should be no differences between them.
I am on M1 Macbook and want to build multi arch image and push it to registry. So I've created new builder with docker-container driver:
docker buildx create \
  --name multi-platform-builder \
  --driver docker-container \
  --use

With docker buildx ls I can see that new builder is the default one:
% docker buildx ls
NAME/NODE                     DRIVER/ENDPOINT                   STATUS    BUILDKIT   PLATFORMS
multi-platform-builder*       docker-container                                       
 \_ multi-platform-builder0    \_ unix:///var/run/docker.sock   running   v0.15.2    linux/arm64, linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
default                       docker                                                 
 \_ default                    \_ default                       running   v0.13.2    linux/arm64, linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
desktop-linux                 docker                                                 
 \_ desktop-linux              \_ desktop-linux                 running   v0.13.2    linux/arm64, linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6

Now the questions.

If the docker build is an alias for docker buildx build, why this command does not work:

docker build \
--platform=linux/arm64,linux/amd64 \
-t myrepo/myapp:1.0.0 \
-t myrepo/myapp:latest \
--push \
.

and fail with message ERROR: Multi-platform build is not supported for the docker driver. but buildx build version works ok:
docker buildx build \
--platform=linux/arm64,linux/amd64 \
-t myrepo/myapp:1.0.0 \
-t myrepo/myapp:latest \
--push \
.

My Docker Desktop version is 4.30.0 with Docker Engine 26.1.1

all docker builds are performed by buildx. docker build just invokes buildx with the default - legacy - driver.

@ChrisBecke is it possible to switch default driver to docker-container or I should always use buildx build instead of build?

You are correct that docker build is an alias of docker buildx build. However docker build uses the default buildx builder which has docker set a driver and docker driver doesn't support features like Multi-arch images.
To use custom builder with docker build command add a --builder option with the name of your custom builder. So in your case command would look like this.
docker build \
--platform=linux/arm64,linux/amd64 \
-t myrepo/myapp:1.0.0 \
-t myrepo/myapp:latest \
--push \
--builder multi-platform-builder \
.


How do you create "multi-platform-builder" builder?

@majorgear  It's the first command in the question.

How complicated the command set in docker has become lately! I spent hours figuring out why it works in one case and not in another
